# Select all columns matching a specific values which can be empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a query which have multiple input parameter, and some of them can be empty.

This query is used to get the data from the database, depending on the values that the user enters.

For example, he can only choose the beginning and the finishing date with the hour, or just choose the product, etc...

```
SELECT 
    cl.checklist_id AS id,
    cl.checklist_indice AS indice,
    cl.checklist_produit_id AS produitId,
    cl.checklist_personne_id AS personneId,
    cl.checklist_date AS date,
    cl.checklist_heure AS heure,
    cl.checklist_machine_id AS machineID
FROM
    checklist cl,
    personne p,
    produit pr
WHERE cl.checklist_id IN (SELECT 
            cl.checklist_id
        FROM
            checklist cl
        WHERE
           :heureStart <= cl.checklist_heure
                AND cl.checklist_heure <= :heureEnd
                AND cl.checklist_id IN (SELECT 
                    cl.checklist_id
                FROM
                    checklist cl
                WHERE
                    :dateStart <= cl.checklist_date
                        AND cl.checklist_date <= :dateEnd
                        AND cl.checklist_id IN (SELECT 
                            cl.checklist_id
                        FROM
                            checklist cl
                        WHERE
                            cl.checklist_produit_id = :produitId
                                AND cl.checklist_id IN (SELECT 
                                    cl.checklist_id
                                FROM
                                    checklist cl
                                WHERE
                                    cl.checklist_machine_id = :machineId
                                        AND cl.checklist_id IN (SELECT 
                                            cl.checklist_id
                                        FROM
                                            checklist cl
                                        WHERE
                                            cl.checklist_personne_id = :personneId)))));
```

If I want this query to work, I must fill all the values to get the data.

Is there a way to get all the data from a column if the values is empty  (like a `SELECT *` on the column) ? Do I need to make a query for every possibility ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this query? You have to query for every possibility, but not in a nested query like you did...

```
SELECT cl.checklist_id AS id,
  cl.checklist_indice AS indice,
  cl.checklist_produit_id AS produitId,
  cl.checklist_personne_id AS personneId,
  cl.checklist_date AS date,
  cl.checklist_heure AS heure,
  cl.checklist_machine_id AS machineID
FROM checklist cl, personne p, produit pr
WHERE (:heureStart is null OR :heureStart <= cl.checklist_heure)
      AND ((:dateStart is null AND :dateEnd is null) OR (:dateStart <= cl.checklist_date AND cl.checklist_date <= :dateEnd))
      AND (:produitId is null OR cl.checklist_produit_id = :produitId)
      AND (:machineId is null OR cl.checklist_machine_id = :machineId)
      AND (:personneId is null OR cl.checklist_personne_id = personneId);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer !
But in my database the columns are never empty so I must fill all the input on my form to get the data, so I face the same kind of problem.. Or maybe I've misunderstood something.

Comment: I'm not checking that the database column is empty, I'm checking that your input on your form is empty. So either your input from your form for that field is empty, or you compare it to values in your database...

Comment: I've found that the error is caused by an illegal mix of collations. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the query that successfully fit my problem, here it is :

```
SELECT cl.checklist_id AS id,
    cl.checklist_indice AS indice,
    cl.checklist_produit_id AS produitId,
    cl.checklist_personne_id AS personneId,
    cl.checklist_date AS date,
    cl.checklist_heure AS heure,
    cl.checklist_machine_id AS machineId

FROM checklist cl

WHERE (cl.checklist_date BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd)
    AND (cl.checklist_heure BETWEEN :heureStart AND :heureEnd)
    AND cl.checklist_produit_id REGEXP :produitId
    AND cl.checklist_machine_id REGEXP :machineId
    AND cl.checklist_personne_id REGEXP :personneId;
```

And this is the PHP code (for every variable you must check this):

```
if(strlen($variable) == 0){
            $variable= "^.*$";
}
```

The REGEXP match all character, from a sequence size from 0 to ∞ (infinite).